# How to initialise an integer array inside a foreach loop in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I have the following code in the controller of Codeigniter project:

```
foreach($attendace as $k => $v) { 
$id = $v['project_id'];
$result[$id]['project_name'] = $v['project_name']; 
$result[$id]['labour'] += $v['no_of_labours']; 
$result[$id]['total_time'] += ($v['stop_time']-$v['start_time'])*$v['no_of_labours']; 
}
```

This code gives an error unknown variable labour and total_time. And if I try to initialise these variables as following:

```
 foreach($attendace as $k => $v) { 
    $id = $v['project_id'];
    $result[$id]['labour'] =0;
    $result[$id]['total_time']=0;
    $result[$id]['project_name'] = $v['project_name']; 
    $result[$id]['labour'] += $v['no_of_labours']; 
    $result[$id]['total_time'] += ($v['stop_time']-$v['start_time'])*$v['no_of_labours']; 
    }
```

Adding $result[$id]['labour'] =0; and $result[$id]['total_time']=0; then the added value that I am getting is wrong. Basically it does not add then.

### Hence, could anyone tell me how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (!isset($result[$id]['labour'])) $result[$id]['labour'] = 0;
if (!isset($result[$id]['total_time'])) $result[$id]['total_time'] = 0;
```